# How can I over come the page/grid/panel loading issue in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

How can I over come the page/grid/panel loading issue in selenium. I'm trying to automate an application using selenium and I'm trying to read the value from a popup grid using XPATH value. When I try to read I'm getting element or value can't find.

Please see the code

```
ieDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='showGridMin']//div[@class='datagrid-view2']/div[2]/table[@class='datagrid-btable']/tbody"));
trData = bsdocstable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

Above issue occurred periodically. Also I have limitation to use the browsers. Application only support IE not Firefox or any other browsers.

Thanks

Comment: please provide HTML code for the same and also check once element is inside of iframe or not

Comment: I see that the first line of code here should probably be assigning that element to bsdocstable?  Also, Please show us the specific error message.

Comment: @murali selenium I dont have the html source code. I'm working on exiting application.